# How to copy files from one directory to another in the same PS session

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I want to copy files from a remote session (a VM) and paste them in a different directory in the same session.
The Copy-Item command only allows me to copy from local machine to a remote session and vice versa.

I tried using -FromSession and -ToSession commands but they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: do I understand this correctly: you want to connect to a remote machine and copy files on that remote machine from directory A to directory B?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the exact code you used. What works and what fails?

Comment: I tried this:       

$session = New-PSSession -Computername $vmIP -Credential $VMLogonCred
$createDirCommand = New-Item -Path $InstallerCopyDestination -type directory -Force

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $createDirCommand -Session $session

Copy-Item -Path $InstallerPath -FromSession $session -Destination $InstallerCopyDestination -ToSession $session -Recurse       

However, I cannot use -ToSession and -FromSession at the same time.

Comment: Sorry for the bad format

Comment: Why use a session at all? Can't you use the `Copy-Item` cmdlet using UNC paths for both the source and destination folders? (Copy-Item also has a `-Credential`) parameter..)

Answer (score 0):

As you want to copy files from folderA to folderB on a Windows remote machine you can do:

```
#Define the actions to execute on the remote computer
$scriptBlock = {
    move-item -Path [path] -Destination [path]
}

#Run the command on the remote computer
invoke-command -ComputerName [dnsHostName] -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```